# R Package checking package dependencies ERROR in Travis-ci

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

My package passes local tests with devtools::check(), but fails to build with Travis (https://travis-ci.org/mjockers/syuzhet).  Travis reports a  "checking package dependencies ... ERROR"  because the openNLP Package is required but not available. What is the trick to making the package available to Travis?  Package is here: https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet

Comment: I think you might need to install Java before installing your package, here's an example of how to do that in the .travis.yml: https://github.com/benmarwick/JSTORr/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Thanks Ben.  That did the trick.  Should have thought of the java issue since this has caused other problems in the past. . .

Comment: Great, glad that helped (p.s. I'm a [big fan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16010600/1036500) of your macroanalysis book and related work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to update my .travis.yml file to load java, which the `openNLP` package requires.

I updated .travis.yml by adding

```
language: java
```

and

```
install:
  - sudo R CMD javareconf
```

The complete working version is at https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet/blob/master/.travis.yml

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036500/ben