# R package dependency error on travis-ci but not local machine

Tags: r, version-control, package, travis-ci, mpfr

I am trying to build my first R package ([GitHub link](https://github.com/szipper/streamDepletr)). It is currently passing all local checks with `devtools::check()`, but [failing on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/szipper/streamDepletr):

`ERROR: dependency ‘Rmpfr’ is not available for package ‘streamDepletr’`

Looking at the `Installed package versions` section of the travis-ci output, `Rmpfr` is not listed. However, my [DESCRIPTION file](https://github.com/szipper/streamDepletr/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) includes it as an import:

```
Imports:
  Rmpfr,
    dplyr,
    magrittr
```

and [Rmpfr is available on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html); my question is, how do I get travis-ci to install it?

The solution may be related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554105/r-package-checking-package-dependencies-error-in-travis-ci) where the author had to include Java in their `.travis.yml` file. For [Rmpfr, it looks like the MPFR C library is necessary](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/README.html). Is there a way to instruct travis to install this library in my `.travis.yml` file? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out, you need the `libmpfr-dev` package to be installed. You can do this by adding

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libmpfr-dev
```

to your `.travis.yml`. See [the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/#APT-packages) for reference.